# RHEL8 - Missing yum.log from /var/log/

Tags: rhel, yum, dnf

I am not seeing the log file for yum in the log directory. This is a new VM install. Any assistance in getting thie file created and logs recorded is greatly appricated.  [image]

Answer (score 4):

`yum` has been replaced by `dnf` as the package manager in RHEL 8.

What you're looking for are `dnf.log` and other logfiles.

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to answer. I understand it was a simple issue.